# Spring data projection for native query not mapped to interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-projections

This my repostoriy for retrieve items

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT M.ID as \"id\", "
        + " M.NAME_PRIMARY_LANG as \"name\" "
        + " FROM ECOMMERCE_CORE.MERCHANT_ITEMS M , "
        + " ECOMMERCE_CORE.PRODUCT_UNIT_OF_MEASURE P , "
        + " ECOMMERCE_CORE.LOOKUP_TYPES_STATUS S , "
        + " ECOMMERCE_CORE.ITEM_TYPES T , "
        + " ECOMMERCE_CORE.ITEM_PRICE I,"
        + " ECOMMERCE_CORE.MERCHANT_ITEM_BRAND B, "
        + " ECOMMERCE_CORE.MERCHANT_ITEM_CATEGORY C "
        + " WHERE M.ID = P.PRODUCT_ID AND M.ID=I.PRODUCT_ID AND M.ID = B.MERCHANT_ITEM_ID AND  S.ID=M.STATUS_ID AND M.TYPE = T.ID AND M.MERCHANT_ID =?1 AND M.STATUS_ID =?2 "
        + " AND P.BRANCH_ID = ?3 AND I.CHANNEL_ID = ?4 ",
        nativeQuery = true
)
List<ItemModelProjection> findBySupplierIdAndStatusCode(long id, long status, long branchId, long channelId, Pageable pageable);
```

and this my interface which i need to map the result to it

```
    @Getter
    @EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
    public class ItemModelProjection {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public ItemModelProjection(final String id, final String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }}
```

and the result of this query not mapped to the interface , what is the problem for it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue and achieve the result by using **projections** by making your DTO an interface with getters for columns returned by the query.

All you need to do is to have interface and contain query domains starting with `get`.

```java
public interface ItemModelProjection {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an interface if you want to retrieve those values. And be careful with the naming of the methods. If you have like in your case `AS name` then call the method `getName()`. But if you don't have AS specified and you are returning a value for example like `PRODUCT_UNIT_OF_MEASURE` then use the following method name: `getProduct_Unit_Of_Measure()`.

For getting those two values use the following interface:

```
public interface ItemModelProjection {

  String getId();

  String getName();

}
```